# Reload BrowserSync Only Once When Using Jekyll in Gulp on Shared File Update

Tags: gulp, jekyll, gulp-watch, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I have a Jekyll site which is part of a Gulp project, using BrowserSync to preview the site as it is built. One of my `watch` statements looks for changes to the `html` in order to auto-refresh the site.

```
gulp.watch('docs/_site/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

Works as designed.

However, when I update `header.html` (or any other shared file) the browser is refreshed *multiple* times because *all* the pages changed. This makes sense, since all the static pages are being updated. But I'd like to prevent this when updating a shared file.

Is there a way I can tell Gulp/BrowserSync to only refresh once when a shared Jekyll file is updated?

**UPDATE**

My watch set looks like the following:

```
gulp.task('dev:watch', ['browserSync', 'docs:sass', 'docs:lib', 'docs:build'], function () {
  gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss', 'docs/assets/**/*.scss'], ['dev:sass']);
  gulp.watch(['docs/**/*.html', 'docs/**/*.md', '!docs/_site/**'], ['docs:build']);
  gulp.watch('docs/_site/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

The `docs:build` task:

```
gulp.task('docs:build', function () {
  browserSync.notify('Building Jekyll');
  return spawn('jekyll', ['build', '--config', '_config.yml,_config_dev.yml', '--incremental'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

# **Edit** after your question edition :

Changes in `_site` are consequences of `dev:sass` or `docs:build` tasks, so, you can call `browserSync.reload` from inside those tasks. You will then be sure that it append one time only.

# **End edit**

So, you're watching a watched process.

You have a `jekyll serve` running, which by default is watching any change at the root and that fires a generation for all files including "_includes" files.

For an _include file change, you can have 10 pages + 10 posts + 10 collections items = 30 refreshed pages in _site folder, which leads to 30 gulp.watch updates fired.

You'd better watch basic jekyll files and folder for change with :

```
gulp.watch(
  ['*.html', '*.md',  '_includes/*.html', '_layouts/*.html', ...other files],
  browserSync.reload()
);
```

and even add a [reload delay](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-reloadDelay) to allow jekyll take time to regenerate a big site and reload after a descent time :

```
browserSync.reload({reloadDelay: 5000})
```

Comment: Hi David. I am not running 'jekyll serve', it is just a Jekyll based site (my wording may have been confusing). Gulp is handling all the compiling (through the 'build' process) and the site is being served (during dev) by BrowserSync.

Comment: And how changes in _site happen ? watch -> jekyll build ? Can we see your code ?

Comment: I've updated my question with the `watch` and `build` tasks. Thank you!

Comment: Makes sense. I gave it a go, but it reloads the browser before Jekyll is done. Adding a `reloadDelay` seems to do nothing at all.